# How to Change AppCompatActivity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I am a newbie at develop android app. My tab use fragment but i follow tutorial that use AppCompatActivity can not combine them. I want to learn how to change AppCompatActivity into Fragment.

There are my some code:

**UserInfo.java**This part should use fragment.

```
public class UserInfo extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Bind(R.id.passport_type)
    BetterSpinner spinner_passport;

    public UserInfo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_info);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.passport_type);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);

        spinner_passport.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_info, container, false);
    }

}
```

This is error occurred code:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new UserInfo(), "个人信息");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "健康信息");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "个人证件");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

new UserInfo() has error.
Error Message is:

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_userprofile.UserInfo', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' less... 

addFragment
(android.support.v4.app.Fragment,
String)
in ViewPagerAdapter cannot be applied
to
(com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_userprofile.UserInfo,
String)
```

I  really want to learn how to change to Fragment any tutorial or any help will be appreciated. thanks so much! And i will upload more details if needed.

Comment: Find any tutorial on Fragments... Your error is that you can't load an AppCompatActivity into a ViewPager. Forget about the conversion for a second, and find out how to make and show a simple Fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to figure out how Butterknife works in Fragments, but I think you're close, you need this instead

```
class UserInfo extends Fragment
```

(and make sure you import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`)

Then, preferably move all code from onCreate into OnCreateView and restructure the code like so

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_info, container, false);

// TODO: v.findViewById(R.id.passport_type)
// TODO: Set the adapter 

return v;  // this replaces 'setContentView'
```

Wherever you get an error with `this`, change it to `getActivity()`, and also `getActivity().getResources()`