# Kotlin: Fragment from AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

Converted `AppCompatActivity()` to `Fragment()` and made some changes according to topics:
[How to Change AppCompatActivity to Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776201/how-to-change-appcompatactivity-to-fragment/37776311)
and updated the Gradle [React Native: Unfortunately, Application has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389541/react-native-unfortunately-application-has-stopped).

`carouselView` worked before I made a Fragment view. It compiles:

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /Users/jaskier/Documents/Android/GoodTogether

> Configure project :app
> Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Configure project :tabview
> Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :tabview:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :tabview:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :tabview:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :tabview:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :tabview:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tabview:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :tabview:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 829ms 40 actionable tasks: 40 up-to-date Build
> Analyzer results available

But when I switch this Fragment as active (tabView with fragments) it gives:

> Unfortunately, Application has stopped

What could I miss during conversion from `AppCompatActivity()`?

**BEFORE:**

```
package com.myPackage.application
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_start_carousel.*

class StartCarouselActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val movies = arrayListOf(R.drawable.ic_action_tab1, R.drawable.ic_action_tab2, R.drawable.ic_action_tab3)
    private val moviesTitles = arrayListOf("Harry Potter", "Konosuba", "I Am Legend")
    private val trending = arrayListOf(R.drawable.ic_action_tab1, R.drawable.ic_action_tab2, R.drawable.ic_action_tab3)

    private val trendingTitles = arrayListOf("Lord of the Rings", "The Last Naruto the Movie", "Spirited Away")

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_carousel)

        carouselView1.apply {
            size = movies.size
            resource = R.layout.start_carousel_movies_item
            scaleOnScroll = true
            spacing = 50
            hideIndicator(true)
            setCarouselViewListener { view, position ->
                val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
                imageView.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, movies[position], null))
                val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTitle)
                textView.text = moviesTitles[position]
            }
            show()
        }

        carouselView2.apply {
            val trendingMovies = trending + movies
            val trendingTitle = trendingTitles + moviesTitles

            size = trendingMovies.size
            resource = R.layout.start_carousel_trending_item
            spacing = 50
            hideIndicator(true)
            setCarouselViewListener { view, position ->
                val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
                imageView.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, trendingMovies[position], null))
                val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTitle)
                textView.text = trendingTitle[position]
            }
            show()
        }

    }
}
```

**AFTER:**

```
package com.myPackage.application
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_start_carousel.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_tab2.view.*

class TabFragment2 : Fragment() {
    private val movies = arrayListOf(
        R.drawable.ic_action_tab1,
        R.drawable.ic_action_tab2,
        R.drawable.ic_action_tab3
    )
    private val moviesTitles = arrayListOf("Harry Potter", "Konosuba", "I Am Legend")
    private val trending = arrayListOf(
        R.drawable.ic_action_tab1,
        R.drawable.ic_action_tab2,
        R.drawable.ic_action_tab3
    )

    private val trendingTitles = arrayListOf(
        "Lord of the Rings",
        "The Last Naruto the Movie",
        "Spirited Away"
    )

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_start_carousel, container, false)

        carouselView1.apply {
            size = movies.size
            resource = R.layout.start_carousel_movies_item
            scaleOnScroll = true
            spacing = 50
            hideIndicator(true)
            setCarouselViewListener { view, position ->
                val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
                imageView.setImageDrawable(
                    ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
                        resources,
                        movies[position],
                        null
                    )
                )
                val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTitle)
                textView.text = moviesTitles[position]
            }
            show()
        }

        carouselView2.apply {
            val trendingMovies = trending + movies
            val trendingTitle = trendingTitles + moviesTitles

            size = trendingMovies.size
            resource = R.layout.start_carousel_trending_item
            spacing = 50
            hideIndicator(true)
            setCarouselViewListener { view, position ->
                val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
                imageView.setImageDrawable(
                    ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
                        resources,
                        trendingMovies[position],
                        null
                    )
                )
                val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTitle)
                textView.text = trendingTitle[position]
            }
            show()
        }
        return  v
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception you're getting.

Comment: @ianhanniballake added all output data. I think It's about syntax conversion.

Comment: That's not a stack trace of an exception, that's build output. I'm talking about the logcat output that includes the full stack trace of the crash you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your carousel view IDs are carouselView1 and carouselView2 you should use

```
v.findViewById<CarouselView>(R.id.carouselView1).apply { ... }
```

and

```
v.findViewById<CarouselView>(R.id.carouselView2).apply { ... }
```

to instantiate your carousel views in `onCreateView`.

The **apply** function in kotlin is a scope function that refers to the context object (in this case your two `CarouselView`)
and returns it.

So in your case both `v.findViewById<CarouselView>(R.id.carouselView1).apply { ... }` and `v.findViewById<CarouselView>(R.id.carouselView2).apply { ... }`
returns a `CarouselView`.

This behavior could be useful in case you need to use your views globally in the `Fragment`:

```
    private var carouselView1: CarouselView? = null

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_start_carousel, container, false)

        carouselView1 = v.findViewById<CarouselView>(R.id.carouselView1).apply { ... }
    }

    fun exampleFunction() {
        // Example operation to explain the global use of this variable
        carouselView1?.spacing = 10
    }
```

For more information about Kotlin's scope functions see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html).

The main problem with your fragment's code however was that you weren't searching for your `CarouselView` in your inflated view (`v`).
In fact, in your `AppCompactActivity` you didn't need to refer to the specific view before `findViewById` because of the `setContentView` method in `onCreate`,
which automatically inflates the layout.

These are the reason for the code syntax `v.findViewById<ViewType>(<view-id>)`.

Comment: could you explain please how **apply** works and why we did so?
**Replaced carouselView1.apply** with your code. Seems to work somehow now!
More people can search for such a helpful solution.

Comment: Just edited the answer with an explanation of the code